# While creating a node, I want to change the value of textfield using ajax based on the value of preceeding drop-down list. Here is the following code

Tags: ajax

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
                $form['field_parent_name']['und']['#options'] = $option_list;
                $form['field_parent_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] =  array(
                       'callback' => 'parent_display_name',
                       'wrapper' => 'field-parent-display-name-add-more-wrapper',
                       'method' => 'replace',
                       'effect' => 'fade',
                     );
           if (isset($form['field_parent_name'])) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'account_node')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

  $query->fieldCondition('field_node_name', 'value', $form_state['values']['parent_node'], '=');
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (!empty($result)) {
    $node_objects = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
    $node_key = key($node_objects);
  }
  $gname = $node_objects[$node_key]->title;
}

         $form['field_parent_display_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#value']=$gname;


        }}



    function parent_display_name(&$form, &$form_state) {  
    return $form['field_parent_display_name'];
     }
```

I m not able to access $form_state . Even if I pass values like $gname=rand(),still no effect on ajax.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)?

Comment: The values i.e $option_list change dynamically. I wont be able to use conditional fields in that case